# PowerShell : How to run remote command prompt commands as admin from PowerShell?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, powershell-3.0, powershell-remoting

My scenario : Login to the remote machine via remote desktop connection and open command prompt as admin and execute some admin commands in the command prompt.

I am trying to automate the above scenario through powershell from my local machine.

Below are the steps that I have done :

1. To check the working of my powershell script, I manually logged into the remote machine (Admin Cred) and executed this command `Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c cmdcommand > output.txt -Verb runas`. This is working as expected in the remote machine as I am getting the desired output.
2. Now, I tried to execute this command from the local powershell script through `Invoke-Command -ComputerName computername - ScriptBlock {Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c cmdcommand > output.txt -Verb runas} -Credentials $cred`. I do not get any output.
3. But, when I do try to execute the above command without `runas` paramter, I get the output saying this particular command needs admin credentials which is expected.`Invoke-Command -ComputerName computername - ScriptBlock {Start-Process cmd -ArgumentList '/c cmdcommand > output.txt} -Credentials $cred`.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Execute:

```
 Enable-PSRemoting -Force
```

In an elevated prompt on your target PC. Then `Restart-Service WinRM`

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName $rpc -Credential (Get-Credential)
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I first invoked the windows.powershell session for the remote communication and with that session I was able to execute the remote commands as admin from my client machine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to remote to Default endpoint Microsoft.PoweShell, That means the executing user is an administrator in the destination machine.

But here, I suspect the `cmdcommand` you specified is actually doing some execution which targets a remote resource, hence it will become a dual hope issue.

if so, below article will be a solution for you issue.

Its all about [Credential Delegation](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2012/11/14/enable-powershell-second-hop-functionality-with-credssp/)

Comment: Thank you @Prasoon for the comment. I modified my script a little bit `$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName $remoteComputer -ConfigurationName Windows.PowerShell` and using this session in the invoke command solved my problem. My understanding was that, if we do not explicitly use session, the default session would windows.powershell. I have no idea how this worked. Any explanation for this?

Comment: Default endpoint is `Microsoft.PowerShell`, Probably in your environment, you might have an endpoint named `Windows.PowerShell` . To see the available endpoints, Login to the target machine and see the result of Get-PSSessionConfiguration cmdlet.